# How to clear radio button?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<input type="radio" value="10" name="attack" onClick="sendid(this.value)"/> Attack 1
<input type="radio" value="20" name="attack" onClick="sendid(this.value)"/> Attack 2
```

When I click on the radio, immediately I get the response!
But along with the response, I want to clear the check radio! 
How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using buttons instead...?

Comment: What about a button ?

Comment: it works without button! But do you mean I would need to use a button for that?

Comment: `<button value="10" onclick="sendid(this.value)">Attack</button>`

Comment: I want to refresh the page and then show my response!! ?? :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the checked property to false. I suggest passing the element to your function (not just its value):

```
onClick="sendid(this)"
```

JavaScript:

```
function sendid(element){
    element.checked = false;
}
```

This will work but it doesn't seem like a radio button is the most appropriate tool for this job.

Comment: okk then how should i retrieve the value from the element?